# How to fetch a single row from two rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table called store_contact

```
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+----------------+
| store_contact_numbers_id | phone_number_description | phone_number | destination_id |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+----------------+
|                      121 | Fax                      | 5555555555   |            287 |
|                      123 | Main                     | 4444444444   |            287 |
+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------+----------------+
```

and my required output from the the above table is looks like this:

```
+--------------+------------+
| Phone_Number | Fax_Number |
+--------------+------------+
|  4444444444  | 5555555555 |
+--------------+------------+
```

I have tried something like this:

```
select if(phone_number_description='MAIN',phone_number,'') as Phone_Number,
if(phone_number_description='FAX',phone_number,'')  as Fax_Number
 from store_contact where destination_id=287
```

but my above query return something like this:

```
+--------------+------------+
| Phone_Number | Fax_Number |
+--------------+------------+
|              | 5555555555 |
| 44444444444  |            |
+--------------+------------+
```

My query returns two rows one with empty, but I need single row.
can any one please guide me in a right direction to get it done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN phone_number_description='Main' THEN Phone_Number END) Phone_Number,
  MAX(CASE WHEN phone_number_description='Fax' THEN Phone_Number END) Fax_Number
FROM
  store_concat
WHERE
  destination_id=287
GROUP BY
  destination_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT (SELECT IF(phone_number_description = 'MAIN', phone_number, '') 
        FROM   store_contact 
        WHERE  destination_id = 287) AS Phone_Number, 
       (SELECT IF(phone_number_description = 'FAX', phone_number, '') 
        FROM   store_contact 
        WHERE  destination_id = 287) AS Fax_Number
```

Instead of using `IF` blocks, use `CASE`. It's more standard.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it gives me error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"

Comment: Then add `LIMIT 1` after the filter in each subquery.

Comment: Ooch... Sorry I am afraid I must downvote the answer. Not only the query is ugly and sub-optimal, but the `LIMIT 1` hack is a dirty workaround. There are probably more than one Phone number or Fax Number for a given store (a case which I realize I didn't account for either btw).

Answer (score 1):

This table must be related to another `store` table. And I am guessing you actually want to display some details from a store along with its contact details.

To do this, JOIN the `store_contact` twice to this `store` table. Think of the `store_contact` table as if it were two separate tables, the one holding phone numbers only, the other holding fax numbers only. I am assuming `store_contact.destination_id` is a foreign key to `store`.

```
SELECT
    store.name, -- and other fields as required
    phone.phone_number AS phone_number,
    fax.phone_number AS fax_number
FROM store
JOIN store_contact AS phone
    ON (phone.destination_id = store.id AND phone.phone_number_description = 'Main')
JOIN store_contact AS fax
    ON (fax.destination_id = store.id AND fax.phone_number_description = 'Fax')
WHERE destination_id = 287
```

For the very specific result you asked for, this will suffice:

```
SELECT
    phone.phone_number AS phone_number,
    fax.phone_number AS fax_number
FROM store_contact AS phone
JOIN store_contact AS fax USING (destination_id)
WHERE destination_id = 287
AND phone.phone_number_description = 'Main'
AND fax.phone_number_description = 'Fax'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this query is giving me 4 rows instead of one.

Comment: @subodh There must be several phone numbers or fax numbers for one given store. Please post the output of `SELECT store_contact_numbers_id, phone_number_description, phone_number, destination_id FROM store_contact WHERE destination_id = 287`.